# Связи в Entity Frmework 7

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework, uwp, entity-framework-core

Проект C# UWP Windows 10

Пытаюсь разобраться c EF7.

Есть два класса (таблицы):

```
[Table("Transactions")]
public class Transaction
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    publi List<Guid> Tags { get; set; }

    ...
}

[Table("Tags")]
public class Transaction
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

Как определить такую связь в данном фреймворке?

**UPD:** Главное то что поле `Tags` в таблице `Transactions` необходимо именно в виде `List<Guid>`, т.к. в данном случае это еще и `JsonProperty`, но и связь для навигации тоже нужна...

**UPD2:** Будет ли работать такой код?

```
[JsonProperty("tag")]
List<Guid> TagsId { get; set; }
[JsonIgnore, ForeignKey("TagsId")]
public List<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
```

Comment: Вам принципиально использовать `EF7`, что-то я не слышал что он уже официально выпущен. `EF6` не подойдет?

Comment: @sp7 не принципиально, но документации EF6 в WUP для Windows 10 я не нашел

Answer (score 1):

Как я понимаю, вы хотите иметь связь `Один ко Многим` между `Transaction` и `Tag`?

Подкорректируйте свои классы следующим образом:

```
public class Transaction
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

    public Transaction()
    {
        Tags = new List<Tag>();
    }
}


public class Tag
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

Далее достаточно создать класс контекста:

```
public class EFDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Transaction> Transaction { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

И при первом обращении к контексту все остальное EF сделает за вас

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        EFDbContext context = new EFDbContext();

        context.Tags.Count();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

---

Теперь при обращении к свойству `transaction.Tags` из БД будут возвращены все связанные с данной транзакцией сущности `Tag`.

---

Если Вы добавите атрибут `[JsonProperty("tag")]`

```
Transaction tr = new Transaction() { Id = Guid.NewGuid() };
tr.Tags.Add(new Tag() { Id = Guid.NewGuid()});
tr.Tags.Add(new Tag() { Id = Guid.NewGuid() });

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tr);
```

то JSON в вашем случае будет выглядеть так:

`{"Id":"a535ee64-48a8-4f53-89f2-a8afc5443ca2","tag":[{"Id":"a02fcf7f-75ff-4851-b8cf-cac050e0531d"},{"Id":"41aab533-a775-4050-a5e4-d386e2a4b3d7"}]}`

Comment: `public virtual List<Tag> Tags { get; set; }` - если это поле будет помечено `как [JsonProperty("tag")]`, а в Json должен попасть `List<Guid>` - это сработает корректно?

Comment: @SYL, а зачем вам ещё и JSON, кроме EF? Всмысле, зачем информация хранится сразу в двух местах?

Comment: @Monk В Json она не хранится. Она с него приходит и в него потом должна уходить для синхронизации с сервером

Comment: @Monk дополнил вопрос

Comment: SYL, а зачем такое городить в коде. Это как минимум не правильно с точки зрения архитектуры. Почему не формировать нужные `DTO` и потом их сериализовать  в `JSON`?

Comment: Ну в сущности `Tag` по факту гораздо больше полей, поэтому Json будет иметь неверный формат

Comment: SYL, смотрите. Вы формируете нужную по структуре `DTO`, затем преобразуете (маппите) вашу сущность `Tag` в эту `DTO`. Далее  `DTO` сериализуете в `Json`.